# PHP variable for timezone

Tags: php, timezone

I'm asking about PHP contants for timezones name

**For Example :**

```
$rc = date_default_timezone_set("US/Mountain");
```

`"US/Mountain"` to be constants not write it as text

is it exist from PHP classes or I need to do it myself

Thanks in advance

Comment: DateTimeZone::UTC it return 1024
I need to add something like that or find similar in PHP
XYZ::US_Mountain return US/Mountain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such a thing as a predefined constant for this because simply it's not needed. `date_default_timezone_set` works with a string. If you want a constant then you can define one yourself:

```
define('MY_CONSTANT', "US/Mountain");
```

and obviously use it as:

```
date_default_timezone_set(MY_CONSTANT);
```

Comment: Constant to be used immediately after definition and just once. Seems reasonable.

Comment: @zerkms, thats what the OP is asking. I don't understand what could solve indeed.

Comment: yep. That's why instead of giving mostly useless answer I asked a question in a comments :-)

Comment: @zerkms, you didn't understand what I said: I didn't say I haven't understood the question, I said I don't understand what the OP is trying to accomplish in his project, and I relatively care. He asked a quite precise question: are there any predefined constants or classes for things such as "US/Mountain"? and I answered "No, but you could define one". Seems reasonable to me :)

Comment: @MichealMounerMikhailYoussif, nope.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the information on this page:

http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

To build a list of "valid constants" or do whatever you want. Interestingly, on this page:

http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php

It says that you can also do this:

```
date_default_timezone_set ( "Etc/GMT-8" );
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention the timezone yourself. There are not any inbuilt classes or something else for that..

Answer (score 0):

No PHP constants are there to represent particular time zone.You can set ur time zone using

```
<?php
$timezone = "urtimezone";
if(function_exists('date_default_timezone_set')) date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
echo date('d-m-Y H:i:s');
?>
```

List of Supported Timezones can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)